# Flash Builder 4.7 debug ADL "Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger."

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I'm trying to debug an air app. Something I've done probably no less than 1000 times. I know I've fubar'ed some config on my machine. But for the life of me I can't figure out what.

Things I've tried:

1. Changing the SDK (4.6, 4.10, 4.14)
2. Reinstall Flash Builder 4.7
3. I can see Flash Builder listening on port 7935

Flash Builder just times out trying to connect.

Ideas?

Comment: Did you read this?
https://sunilanair.wordpress.com/2009/12/24/air-process-terminated-without-establishing-connection-to-debugger/

Comment: I have... if you only you could see my google search... all the links are purple. I have windows and a mac machine at work so I just switched machines... I'll try solving it again later today.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out…

We have to edit our host files at work to spoof different hostnames and I had removed this entry:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

After putting that back Flash Builder was able to connect fine.